# Unable to click/select the element from dropdown

Tags: java, angular, selenium, xpath

I am unable to find an element using xpath by its text or by any other attribute.

```html
<li class ="grid-class">
 <a tabindex="0">
  <label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" value="ATTR_4">
    " ATTR_4"
  </label>
 </a>
</li>
```

Xpath's I have tried as:

- `//*[@id='multiSel']/div//li[@class='grid-class']//label/input[@value='ATTR_4']`
- `//*[@id='multiSel']/div//li[@class='grid-class']//label/input[text()='ATTR_4']`
- `//*[@id="multiSel"]/div/ul/li[26]/a/label/text()`

Comment: Please post track trace here. Cannot identify your issue without error details. and also add how you are going to send data. So it will be easy to provide answer.

Comment: Please see the updated details @Devdun

Comment: I tried: `public WebElement attrDescVal() {
  WebElement attrDescVal = getElement(Identifier.xpath,
    "//*[@id=\"multiSel\"]/div/ul/li[5]/a/label/text()");
  return attrDescVal;
 }` @Devdun

Comment: These all above mentioned xpaths itself not wokring and I will be directly clicking on that element @Devdun

Comment: Do the attr numbers change every session or do they stay the same?

Comment: There are about 90 attributes in dropdown and remains same @NaveenChandar

Answer (score 0):

The relevant XPath locator would be:

```
//input[@value='ATTR_4']
```

[image]

or if you want to use text instead of the value attribute:

```
//input[contains(text(), 'ATTR_4')]
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

You might also want to consider using [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) as it could be the case the [radio button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) you're looking for is not immediately available in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

Comment: I did tried first way (//input[@value='ATTR_4'] but through that as well the element/option was not getting selected from dropdown though I am able to find it but not click

Comment: Getting element not found exception when try to click the element @Dmitri T